# Runtime error when creating dynamic multidimensional array of pointers (char**)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to create dynamic multidimensional array char** variable to store three strings, but an unknown error occurs at runtime.

```
// Allocate memory for three strings
char **str = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    str[i] = (char*) malloc(20);

// Assign value to each string item
strcpy(str[0], "LionKing");
strcpy(str[1], "Godzilla");
strcpy(str[2], "Batman");

// Print the strings
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%s\n", *str[i]);

// Free the memory of the three strings
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    free(str[i]);
// Free the memory of the main pointer
free(str);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Activate the warnings in your compiler and read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%s\n", *str[i]);` should be `printf("%s\n", str[i]);`.

`*str[i]` is a `char` but `%s` requires a `char *`. Your compiler should have warned you about this. If it did not, enable warnings in your compiler, and pay attention to them.